# How can I programatically add a chain to a wallet?

Tags: ethers.js, wagmi

Trying to implement a function which switches chains to a supported chain with **wagmi** gives me issues on mobile.

I'm working on a project where I need to approve a transaction on a respective chain. Working with **wagmi/core**, using **switchNetwork**, it prompts the user to add the chain to the wallet if it's not already detected. This works on desktop, but doesn't work on mobile. On mobile it opens the wallet, then immediately closes it again, navigates back to the app and throws an error saying `error switching chains` .

Can't find on how to programmatically add a chain to the users wallet with **wagmi** (without switching since that obviously doesn't work).

Also open to suggestions on how this could be done with **ethers.js**.